# How do I save a ternsorflow keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save, h5py

I am trying to save a tensorflow keras model with this summary:

```
Model: "sequential_2" etc.
```

using the following command:

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

I got the following error (in Jupyter Notebook):

```
ImportError: `save_model` requires h5py.
```

So, I installed h5py, using
`conda install h5py`
After the installation, I got the version of h5py in the Jupyter Notebook(same place I am trying to save the model):

```
h5py.__version__
'2.8.0'
```

Still, I got the same error.
Even though, I imported h5py manually.

```
import h5py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
filename = 'model.h5' 
model.save(filename)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
**ImportError**                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-9160eee81fe6> in <module>
      5 from tensorflow.keras import layers
      6 filename = 'model.h5'
----> 7 model.save(filename)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in save_model_to_hdf5(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)

**ImportError:** save_model requires h5py.
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and you installed `h5py` for one Python but you run code with other Python. Every Python has own folder with modules and often can't share with other version.

Comment: Check what @furas have commented. Check 
Which version of python you are running tensorflow with? 
 Is conda install installing for the same python version? 
 Are you using a virtual environment? If yes, then you have to install packages in that environment.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question, I think this should answer the questions, I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libhdf5.  see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422817/keras-importerror-save-model-requires-h5py-even-thought-the-code-already-imp

Comment: That did not fix the problem, actually, 'sudo apt-get' does not work (and apprently there is no online doc to say how to install it, I went through all stack overflow and others for several hours) and I ran brew install for hdf5, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly installing **h5py**?

If you have an existing Python installation (e.g. a python.org download, or the one that comes with your OS), then on Windows, macOS/OSX, and Linux on Intel computers, pre-built h5py wheels can be installed via pip from PyPI:

```
$ pip install h5py
```

In **Windows**:

If that fails you can try installing cython

`pip install h5py`

`pip install cython`

In **Linux/Ubuntu**: 

If that fails then you may also need libhdf5
installing libhdf5 and then installing h5py

1. `sudo pip install cython`

2. `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`

3. `sudo pip install h5py`

**Note:** If the above installation didn't work try uninstalling h5py and then reinstall it and restart the jupyter notebook or anaconda.